# Strlen subroutine (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm trying to write a strlen subroutine in MIPS.
The function works when the string is in memory, but if the string is an input from the user, the answer is always = (correct_value + 1).
For example:

```
String: Hello
Length: 6
```

Why isn't it working for inputs? Here is my code. I'm using MARS.

```
    .data
str1:   .asciiz String: "
strTest:.space 20
str2:   .asciiz "Length: "
    .text
    .globl main

main:  
    addiu   $sp, $sp, -4            # save space
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)             # push $ra

    la      $a0, str1               # print(str1)
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    li      $a1, 20                 # read strTes
    la      $a0, strTest
    li      $v0, 8
    syscall


    jal     strlen                  # call strlen

    move    $t0, $v0                # save result to $t0

    la      $a0, str2               # print str2
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    move    $a0, $t0                # print result
    li      $v0, 1
    syscall

    lw      $ra, 0($sp)             # restore $ra
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 4             # restore $sp
    jr      $ra


strlen:
    li      $v0, 0                  # len = 0

while:  lb      $t0, ($a0)              # get char
    beqz    $t0, wh_end             # if(char == '\0') --> end while
    addi    $v0, $v0, 1             # len++
    addiu   $a0, $a0, 1             # *s++
    j       while
wh_end:
    jr      $ra
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that MARS also includes the enter/return that is pressed after the user inputs his/her string. Your code looks fine, so it would be most logical that MARS returns `"hello\n"` instead of `"hello"`, like you would want it to.

To solve this, you could add a check like you did for `"\0"`, but then for `"\n"`. I'm not sure if it will work, but you could try to add

```
subi $t1, $t0, 10
beqz $t1, wh_end
```

after `beqz $t0, wh_end`. This could work since the ASCII value of the \n termination character is 10, so if you subtract 10 from $t0, and end up with 0, you have a termination character.

Good luck!

Comment: Yep, that did it!
I added
    beq $t0, '\n', wh_end
It seems that MARS adds the '\n' char. Thanks for the help!